# How should I apply a conditional class for nested objects in angularjs

Tags: css, arrays, class, object, angularjs

I'm essentially trying to show/hide the title of a section, based on a click event that is also being used to filter an `ng-repeat` below the title.

My thoughts were to toggle a class by reusing the `ng-click` that I'm utilizing for the filter functionality. My filter is working perfectly on the ng-repeat, however I can't seem to get the conditional classes to work on the heading.

Below is the (simplified) code:

```
<div ng-init="phones = [
            {name:'Samsung Galaxy S II', product_type: 'android'},
            {name:'iPhone 5', product_type: 'ios'},
            {name:'Samsung Galaxy S II', product_type: 'android'},
            {name:'iPhone 5', product_type: 'ios'},
            {name:'Samsung Galaxy S II', product_type: 'android'},
            {name:'iPhone 5', product_type: 'ios'}
        ]">

    <!-- Filters for products -->

    <a href="#" ng-click="property = null">All</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="property = {product_type:'android'}">Android</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="property = {product_type:'ios'}">iOS</a>

    <!-- Android Product Section -->

    <h2 ng-class="{true: 'hide', false: 'show'}[property == {product_type:'ios'}]">Android</h2>

    <div ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:property | filter:{product_type:'android'}">
        <h3>{{ phone.name }}</h3>
    </div>

    <!-- iOS Product Section -->

    <h2 ng-class="{true: 'hide', false: 'show'}[property == {product_type:'android'}]">iOS</h2>  

    <div ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:property | filter:{product_type:'ios'}">
        <h3>{{ phone.name }}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo of my code: http://codepen.io/micjamking/pen/c0cfb8039492204d0282c42f563983e0

FYI, I cannot change the structure/scheme of the JSON (array of objects) above. I'm actually getting the data from an API in a service, but thought this would be an easy way show everything that's going on in the view.

I sincerely appreciate anyones help or advise on this.

Comment: Can you try to change the expression `property == {product_type:'android'}` to `"property.product_type==='android'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `ng-class` directive was a bit more complicated than it needed to be.  I updated it to look like this:

```
<h2 ng-class="{invisible: property.product_type =='ios'}">Android</h2>
...
<h2 ng-class="{invisible: property.product_type =='android'}">iOS</h2>
```

Here's a jsFiddle to demonstrate:  http://jsfiddle.net/jandersen/ZFDQT/1/

(the `invisible` class is taken from your codepen example)